# Laravel show in the table nested categories with parent_id

Tags: laravel, nested

I have categories table (id,  category_name, parent_id) with following data.

id-category_name-parent_id 
1-Electronics-NULL
2-Mobile Phones-1
3-Smart Watches-1
4-Laptops-1
5-Batteries-4

In the Controller retrieves all categories that parent_id is NULL

```
public function index()
{
    $categories = Category::whereNull('parent_id')->get();
    return view('catalogs.categories.v2.index',compact('categories'));
}
```

In the index.blade.php I tried something using treeview heirarchy

```
<tbody>
@foreach($categories as $category)
    <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>{{ $category->category_name }}</td>
          <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>
               {{ $category->category_name }}
               @if(count($category->childs))
                   @include('catalogs.categories.v2.manageChild',['childs' => $category->childs])
               @endif
          </td>
          <td>{{$category->childs_count()  }}</td>
          <th></th>
   </tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>

@foreach($childs as $child)
  >> {{ $child->category_name }}</span>
 @if(count($child->childs))
    @include('catalogs.categories.v2.manageChild',['childs' => $child->childs])
 @endif
@endforeach
```

Now, my output in my table in the view is like as

Category Name
Electronics 
Electronics >> Mobile Phones >> Smart Watches >> Battery >> Laptops

I want to create something like this 
Category Name 
Electronics 
Electronics >> Mobile Phones
Electronics >> Smart Watches
Electronics >> Laptops >> Battery

Can anyone how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can imagine your categories as nodes and the relations between theme as edges

so to search in depth for each category's sons you need to use graph search algorithms such like DFS,

in this link you could know more better about DFS:
[DFS IN GENERAL](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/depth-first-search-or-dfs-for-a-graph/)

[show case for similar problem solved IN DFS](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-a-binary-tree-print-all-root-to-leaf-paths/)